# XSL-FO border-overlapping graphic

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have some problems with realizing the following layout in XSL-FO:

[image]

I thought that I'd create a simple block with a solid black border around it. 
Then I'd place the image on the top-right corner in this block, so that it overlays the border. At the end I could give a left and bottom border to this image.

EDIT: This is my code for placing the image..In the first block i'll tried to place the image from inside the block, and in the second from outside the block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <!-- Layout-->
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name = "ticket_layout"
                                                page-height = "297mm"
                                                page-width = "210mm"
                                                margin-left = "10mm"
                                                margin-right = "5mm"
                                                margin-top = "10mm"
                                                margin-bottom = "10mm">

            <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "20mm" margin-top = "25mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <!-- page sequence-->
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference = "ticket_layout">
        <!-- Body-->
        <fo:flow flow-name = "xsl-region-body">
        <!-- Info Image-->
            <fo:block-container position="absolute" bottom="10" left="10">
                <fo:block text-align = "right">
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url('Info_Icon.jpg')" border-left= "1pt solid black" border-bottom = "1pt solid black" content-height = "50%"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <!-- Table-->
                <fo:table margin-top = "2mm" padding-bottom = "230mm" font-family = "Agenda" font-size = "11">
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <!-- InfoBlock1-->
                            <fo:table-cell >
                                <fo:block padding-bottom= "48mm" margin-right = "1mm" margin-bottom = "1mm" border = "1pt solid black" >
                                    <!-- InfoImage-->
                                    <fo:block-container position="absolute" bottom="60" left="110">
                                        <fo:block text-align = "right">
                                            <fo:external-graphic src="url('Info_Icon.jpg')" border-left= "1pt solid black" border-bottom = "1pt solid black" content-height = "50%"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:block-container>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <!-- InfoBlock_2-->
                            <fo:table-cell >
                                <fo:block  padding-bottom= "48mm" margin-left = "1mm" margin-bottom = "1mm" border = "1pt solid black">
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

But I have problems placing the image exactly on the border. Is it even possible?

Link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FvVr.jpg

I'd also welcome some other suggestions!

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal XSL-FO example where your problem is still present. That way, people can actually test your code.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I changed the code in my question!

Comment: In my opinion, it would be easier to save the complete structure as an image and then use it as the background of `fo:table-cell`:http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#background-image.

Comment: You could also create a table with two columns and two rows. Make the first cell your 'Wichtige Hinweise' cell, the second one you can write or insert you 'i' into.

Then, create an empty second row that spans across both columns.

Set borders as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, you placed the block containing the {i} image inside the larger block. You'll never get the borders to overlap this way. By definition, one block is inside the other.

There are several prossible solutions:

- create a table with 4 cells, use the cell borders to create your border image
- use a background image (either an external-graphic or an embedded SVG) for the border lines
- use 2 sibling block-containers with absolute-position="absolute" placed to overlap each other, one with the box contents, one with the {i} image